# Flutter delete recorded video file from app

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to upload video to firebase by using `camera` plugin. 
Start recording in the example, looks like this.

```
    Future<String> startVideoRecording() async {
    if (!_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      print('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }

    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Movies/flutter_test';
    await new Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.mp4';

    if (_cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      // A recording is already started, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      videoPath = filePath;
      await _cameraController.startVideoRecording(filePath);
      final animation = _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
      animation.whenComplete(() {
        setState(() {
          onStopButtonPressed();
          _isRecorded = true;
        });
      });
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }
```

And I recorded video successfully. However, looking at iPhone's app storage, app size is over 500MB. It's because I took lots of video for practice purposes. The problem is I don't want to save, just get path and upload.

```
final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

it says creating:

> Path to a directory where the application may place files that are
>   private to the application and will only be cleared when the
>   application itself is deleted.

How can I fix this?
Is it possible not to save in the first place?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you delete the video once you uploaded to firebase? As Firebase supports in offline, storing it locally and uploading when there is a internet feels best option to me.

Comment: Thank you for the comment I’m pretty new in programming. So sorry for the silly questions. How can I delete it? Also what does storing in locally mean?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a file on local storage, you can use the path on where the file was stored and use `delete()` function on File.

```dart
File(filePath).delete();
```